# Select option with '' if prop is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue.js 3 with script setup.

This is inside my template:

```
<select v-model="selectedStatus">
    <option 
v-for="option in statusOptions" 
:value="option.status" 
:selected="status == option.status || (status === null && option.status === '')">
{{ option.label }}
</option>
</select>
```

Inside script setup, I have those definitions:

```
const props = defineProps(['status']);
const selectedStatus = ref(props.status);
const statusOptions = [
    { status: '', label: 'Any' },
    { status: 'error', label: 'Only Error' },
    { status: 'success', label: 'Only Success' }
];
```

I can confirm using VueDevtools that the prop `status` is null. When I add a `console.log` on the `:selected=..` I can see that it actually returns to true in the first iteration.

However, the select box does not preselect 'Any'. What am I missing?

This is how it looks in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: Quik tip: The option would be selected even if `selected="false"`.

Comment: @Amini I am not sue I can follow you. Problem is that the option is not selected.

Comment: Hey, wouldn't only the condition, `selectedStatus == option.status` work in the template?

Comment: @NehaSoni no because '' != null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `:selected` prop is useless if you have a `v-model` on the `<select>` element since it has the priority for the "initial selected value".

Because `status` is `null` and `option.status` is `''`, vue doesn't consider them as equal, hence doesn't preselect "Any".

So the only solution you have here is to be sure `selectedOption` is converted to `''` if it's `null`:

```js
const selectedOption = ref(props.status || '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set status value to null for Any:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const stat = ref(null)
    return { stat }
  },
})
app.component('child', {
  template: `
    <select v-model="selectedStatus">
      <option 
      v-for="option in statusOptions" 
      :value="option.status" 
      :selected="status === option.status || (status === null && option.status === '')">
      {{ option.label }}
      </option>
    </select>
  `,
  props: ['status'],
  setup(props) {
    const selectedStatus = ref(props.status);
    const statusOptions = [
        { status: null, label: 'Any' },
        { status: 'error', label: 'Only Error' },
        { status: 'success', label: 'Only Success' }
    ];
    return { selectedStatus, statusOptions }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child :status="stat"></child>
</div>
```